# wxCharts: cannot open source file <wx/wxcharts.h>

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am tying to use wxCharts in a wxWidgets application developed with visual studio.

I have followed the steps given here:

https://www.wxishiko.com/wxCharts/gettingstarted.html

The build of the library works fine. Afterwards, I add the Additional Directories and libraries in the Visual Studio project, as they mention in the link above. However, when trying to include the wxCharts header file, the following error comes up:

```
cannot open source file "wx/wxcharts.h"
```

I was wondering if this might be because I am also including the header files from wxWidgets:

```
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <wx/wxcharts.h>
#include <wx/tglbtn.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "SerialPort.hpp"
```

And despite being in different added directories, they have the same folder names (e.g. wx/). Might that be a problem? Is the compiler looking for the wxcharts.h file into the wx/ folder in wxWidgets, instead of wxCharts?

I have also made sure the wxcharts.h file is in the included wxCharts directory, so I am not sure what else can be causing that error...

Comment: Your first step is to figure out if that file exists. If it does did you properly add the folder containing the wx folder to your "Additional Include Directories". The compiler searches all of   the entries in the "Additional Include directories" and system headers for the wx folder. If that exists, it looks to see if inside the wx folder it found does `wxcharts.h` exist. Also note that compiler settings in Visual Studio are per configuration so make sure you apply the change to Debug, Release ...

Answer (score -1):

I just had a similar issue which was due to me not configuring my project correctly. Under properties you can select which build you are configuring. Turns out I was working in Debug but editing the Release properties. Once I added them to the build, it worked perfectly.

- Properties >> C/C++ >> General "Additional Include Directories" add "C:\wxCharts\include"
- Properties >> Linker >> Link Library Dependancies Added path C:\wxCharts\lib\vc_lib

You can also test to see if your MSVS has built it correctly by building and running some of the samples in C:\wxCharts\samples, this was the first indication it was something wrong in my project rather than not building correctly.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem when setting up wxWidgets. As a temporary fix I edited the include directory to be the raw path of the lib (My environment variables kinda failed on me). I'm not sure though if you should keep that as a permanent fix...